# Impact of Dropping low selectivity indexes in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

We know  we can calculate  selectivity  by  using below  formulae:-

Sql> `Selectivity = Distinct Values / Total Number Rows;`

Sql>

```
SELECT DISTINCT_KEYS, NUM_ROWS,(DISTINCT_KEYS/NUM_ROWS) AS SELECTIVITY,B.*
        FROM DBA_INDEXES B
        WHERE INDEX_NAME  IN('Idx1','Idx11','Idx2') 
        AND  OWNER NOT IN('SYS','SYSTEM');
```

In my application there are many indexes  having unique key value are 2, 3, 4, or 5 and DBA wants to drop those indexes.

Can any body please  explain me the impact of dropping of low/high selectivity indexes where the number of unique key value are 2, 3, 4, or 5 .
How do we calculate  Unique key value for those indexes .Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Dropping those indexes without a performance test and/or without checking if they are used is a really bad idea.

Let's try an example. Assume that we have a table with orders or something. There is a program that runs every now and then that polls for new records to process. It searches by status. The new orders have status NEW. When they have been processed they get status PROCESSED or REJECTED. In other words there are three possible values. Assume that there are a few million records and that typically there are about a hundred with status NEW.

What happens with the polling times if the index, that is normally very selective for NEW records, is dropped?

For the record I know that it is possible to use NULL for records that should not be indexed and that the data model can be reorganized and so on and so forth, but this is a fairly common solution in the wild. Just dropping the index would hurt.

In summary the impact of dropping a low selectivity index can be a disaster. It can also work well, it depends on the application. A better approach is to enable monitoring and see if the index is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping an index would be an overkill and may have a significant impact on your application. Oracle offers other functions for that.

First consider [INDEX MONITORING](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/index-monitoring), or [Index Usage Tracking](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/index-usage-tracking-12cr2) (if you run already version 12.2 or higher)

A very quick alternative to dropping an index is to make it invisible:

```
ALTER INDEX ind_xyz INVISIBLE;
```

An invisible index is not seen by the optimizer, i.e. it will not used for any query or DML operation. Note, you can bypass this behavior on session level with

```
ALTER SESSION SET OPTIMIZER_USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES = TRUE;
```

If you set this parameter to `TRUE` then the optimizer will use indexes regardless of their visibility. The default value is `FALSE`

Also it should be mentioned that [BITMAP indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/indexes.htm#CIHGAFFF) are actually intended to be low selective - that's the way how they are designed and working optimal.